# Object doesn't support property or method 'bind' - Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

I have build my application in Backbone.js using MVC. Everything, is running fine in Chrome/Firefox/IE 9 and above but not in IE8 and below:-

```
var userDetailView = backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#user-details',
    tagName: 'div',
    template: Handlebars.templates.UserDetails,
    model: userModel,

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        return this;
    }
});
```

I am getting error as below:-

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you included underscore in your project?

Comment: @Crungmungus Yes I have. Its is working in Chrome and Mozilla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is `this.model`? How are you instantiating that view? I'd guess that `this.model` is not what it should be. In a view, the `model` property should be a model instance and you're suppose to say things like:

```
var m = new Model;
var v = new View({ model: m });
```

A model instance will have a [`bind`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) method (AKA `on`) but, in non-stone-age browser, [so will a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

A model "class":

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });
```

is a function (just like anything else you can call `new` on in JavaScript). This means that you can say things like this in newer browsers:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });
var v = new View({ model: M });
```

and `this.model.bind('change', this.render)` will execute inside the `View`, it won't call the `bind` you're looking for but it will call a `bind`, it will call `Function.bind`.

Start passing a model instance to your view and things should start making more sense.

---

**Clarification**: If you check the [MDN Browser compatibility section on `Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility), you'll see that there is no `bind` for functions in IE until IE9. So Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 all support calling `bind` on functions but IE8 does not; this precisely matches the observed behavior.

Comment: He says "Everything, is running fine in Chrome/Firefox/IE 9 and above but not in IE8 and below". Taking his word on that, can we not assume this is a browser-related issue?

Comment: @Crungmungus: Some browsers support `bind` on functions, some do not. The "IE8 and below" is a give away.

Comment: @Crungmungus: You might want to look at the ["Browser compatibility"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) section of the MDN page on `Function.bind` and take particular note of the "IE9" part.

Comment: Yes but I don't understand your point at the end about this.model.bind. That just calls an alias to Backbone.Events.on. Could you clarify? Underscore should cater for the missing bind method with _.bind.

Comment: @Crungmungus: `this.model.bind` is an alias for Backbone's `on` function **if** `this.model` is a model instance. If `this.model` happens to be a function (such as `M = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... })`) then `this.model.bind` is the standard `bind` method on JavaScript functions. `Function.bind` is support by every browser in the list **except** IE8 and below.

Comment: Surprisingly.... it WORKS.... Thank you `@mu is too short` for explaining it with so much efforts. Accepted and upvoted.